# Formatting text inside styled circle

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me how I can have the text inside a css styles circle so it comes up down instead of sequential.

Here is the jsfiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/zhxysyrz/`

Here is the code

```
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.roundFormat {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}
</style>

<body>
<span class='roundFormat'>7 Apr</span>

</body>
</html>
```

So inside  the circle instead of having 7 Apr in sequence  how can I make it stacked like below without increasing the circle size.

7
APR

Thanks

Edit: This is the format i want !https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNtje.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can use display: table and disply: table-cell to vertically align the text in the circle and a br so the text drops to the second line.

Here's a solution https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWxbmx

**HTML**

```
<div class='roundFormat'>
    <div class='roundFormatWrap'>7<br>apr</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.roundFormat {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: table;
}

.roundFormatWrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome..Exactly what i was looking for..Thank u so much

Comment: Good one, +1 up

Comment: But if I add something after this it's coming on to a new line..Can this be so the next span is inline..https://jsfiddle.net/zhxysyrz/1/

Comment: You can add float: left; to your .roundFormat class and that will position the text next to the circle. ( see here https://jsfiddle.net/ofvsedx8/ )If you're trying to get the text vertically aligned as well you will probably have to create a new span and keep it inside the .roundFormat class. Let me know if that's what you're trying to do and I can make an update.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.roundFormat {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  
  .roundFormat>span:first-child {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  
  .roundFormat>span:not(:first-child) {
    display: block;
    line-height: 0px;
  }
}
</style>

<body>
  <span class='roundFormat'><span>7</span><span>apr</span></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but ur code snippet is displaying like what I already have sequentially and not stacked.